# DropdownButton failed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following DropdownButton widget:

```
Center(
              child: DropdownButton<dynamic>(
                value: selectedTipoInterno,
                items: dataTiposInt.map(
                  (list) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(list['tipo_int']),
                      value: list['id'],
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            )
```

And here you have the value for dataTiposInt:

```
[{"id":"1","tipo_int":"Administrador"},{"id":"2","tipo_int":"Editor"},{"id":"3","tipo_int":"Supervisor"},{"id":"4","tipo_int":"Analista"},{"id":"5","tipo_int":"Colaborador"}]
```

I am getting the following error output:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Administrador. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 894 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I could just do a little comment but don't have enough reputation yet.

Is the value for `datatiposInt` written like that in your code? Or is it generated? If the latter, it might be helpful to see that code as well.

Also, I'm guessing that your `selectedTipoInterno` is not of type String, so I'm wondering if that throws off the dropdown in general

Comment: The value of dataTiposInt is generated  by a future:

Comment: The issue was the initialization of selectesTipoInterno, it must be equal to one of the dataTipoInt values.

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling that was it